# Install mechanize-firefox module on ActivePerl

Tags: perl, firefox, www-mechanize

I cannot find mechanize-firefox module on ActivePerl by using ppm [Perl Package Manager] in win7. Do you have any alternative way or method to install this module? Thank you for your sharing valuable experience. Thank you.

Comment: FWIW, complain to activestate about this.  They are not building IPC::Run (an indirect dependency of WWW::Mechanize::Firefox) because its build is taking longer than their system allows.  IPC::Run is an important dependency and they should look at fixing their build process.  (Unless maybe the tests are actually hanging, in which case they should be reporting that to the IPC::Run maintainer)

Comment: (mandatory comment about how nice it is of activestate to provide all this free stuff, in addition to their support of and involvement in perl development over the years...)

Answer (score 0):

I also can not in ppm.
I have manually installed [WWW::Mechanize::Firefox](http://metacpan.org/pod/WWW%3a%3aMechanize%3a%3aFirefox)

1,WWW-Mechanize-Firefox-0.68.tar.gz [Download]
2,Expansion
3,perl Makefile.PL-> make -> make test ->make install->ok

success